# Automation Query Error in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, automation

I am running the Query using Automation with the help of Data Extension, it is showing error like

> String or binary data would be truncated.

[image]

But i have the Maximum field length also, what ever i have give the value it is showing error,How to Rectify the Error

[image]

Any Help Appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is with `SMTPBounceReason`. This field can return an excess of 4000 characters. To bypass this, remove leave the length field blank. This will force it to `VARCHAR(MAX)` (Over 4000 characters).

Resources:

- [Override Maximum Character Length](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000220898&language=en_US&type=1)

Comment: Is there a way to get the actual field name that is causing this? I have the same error, however it is a bunch of custom fields that I have, so I am quite lost as i am no tsure if i should just test 1 by one?

Answer (score 1):

[Incase anyone else comes across this issue...]

Useful article on how to optimize SQL queries:

- [Optimize SQL Query Activities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000249248&type=1)

> **Relational Data**
>
> The Marketing Cloud data environment, exposed via Data Extensions, is
>   relational. It is possible to designate fields in Data Extensions as a
>   Primary Key. The values stored therein can similarly be placed in
>   another Data Extension to operate as a Foreign Key. By doing so, those
>   two data sets can be logically linked to enable greater sophistication
>   for data storage and analysis procedures.
>
> Any Data Extension spanning a cumulative field width greater than 4000
>   characters must be avoided. Avoiding excessive width is typically
>   achieved by use of two Data Extensions that have been related via a
>   Primary/Foreign Key relationship.